# How reduceByKey in RddPair<K,Tuple> in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have this a CassandraTable. Access by SparkContext.cassandraTable(). Retrieve all my CassandraRow.

Now I want to store 3 information: (user, city, byte)
I store like this

```
rddUsersFilter.map(row =>
(row.getString("user"),(row.getString("city"),row.getString("byte").replace(",","").toLong))).groupByKey
```

I obtain a RDD[(String, Iterable[(String, Long)])]
Now for each user I want to sum all bytes and create a Map for city like: "city"->"occurencies" (how many time this city appairs for this user).

Previously, I split up this code in two differnt RDD, one to sum byte, the other one to create map as described.

Example for occurency for City

```
rddUsers.map(user => (user._1, user._2.size, user._2.groupBy(identity).map(city => (city._1,city._2.size))))
```

that's because I could access to second element of my tuple thanks to ._2 method. But now?
My second element is a Iterable[(String,Long)], and I can't map anymore like I did before.

Is there a solution to retrieve all my information with just one rdd and a single MapReduce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this easily by first grouping bytes and city occurrence for user,city and then do a group by user

```
val data = Array(("user1","city1",100),("user1","city1",100),
     ("user1","city1",100),("user1","city2",100),("user1","city2",100), 
     ("user1","city3",100),("user1","city2",100),("user2","city1",100),
     ("user2","city2",100))
val rdd = sc.parallelize(data)

val res = rdd.map(x=> ((x._1,x._2),(1,x._3)))
             .reduceByKey((x,y)=> (x._1+y._1,x._2+y._2))
             .map(x => (x._1._1,(x._1._2,x._2._1,x._2._2)))
             .groupByKey
val userCityUsageRdd = res.map(x => { 
 val m = x._2.toList
 (x._1 ,m.map(y => (y._1->y._2)).toMap, m.map(x => x._3).reduce(_+_))
})
```

output

```
res20: Array[(String, scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int], Int)] = 
Array((user1,Map(city1 -> 3, city3 -> 1, city2 -> 3),700), 
      (user2,Map(city1 -> 1, city2 -> 1),200))
```

Comment: But, For each User i want to sum all bytes, no matter what city it belongs to. So if (user1,100,city1),(user1,200,city1),(user1,50,city2) I want something like -> (user1,350,Map(city1->2,city2->1))